# Delay between statements in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I want some delay between the object operations in a for-loop in *Matlab*. Such that, the initialization of objects having some delay, like I have a set of **100** objects, I stored their declaration in cell array, now I want some set of operations to them BUT with first **5** objects first, then after **5-sec** next five and so on. May is it possible their declaration is also in loop?   `Pause()` and `delay()` functions do not work for me as they apply on the whole loop and all objects stop for a while.

**My Code:**

```
Dec= cellfun(@(x) ['Obj' num2str(x)], num2cell(1:100)', 'UniformOutput', false); %declaration
for ii=1:1000 
    for jj=1:100 % loop for object numbering and operations
        Obj{jj}=[1:10];
    end
end
```

My code just took all objects at a time and starts operations on them, but I need a *delay/pause* such that a after `[1:5]` of first **5** objects, next  **5** objects start their `[1:10]` and so on. I think I cleared my problem statement. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% certain I know what you're trying to do, but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
Dec= cellfun(@(x) ['Obj' num2str(x)], num2cell(1:100)', 'UniformOutput', false); %declaration
for ii=1:1000 
    if (rem(ii, 5) == 0)
        pause(1);
    end
    for jj=0:100 % loop for object numbering and operations
        Obj{jj}=[1:10];
    end
end
```

If that isn't what you need, let me know and I'll take another shot at it.

Comment: It isn't. in simple words, I have 100 objects, I want first five `[1:5]` then next five `[1:10]` and mean while. first five have `[6:10]` like this.

Comment: Try it now, I just submitted an edit. I don't understand what you mean by " then next five [1:10] and mean while first five have [6:10]" I just can't parse that.

Comment: Undefined function or variable 'delay'.

Comment: Try it now, sorry, I mixed up languages.

Comment: Haha, no problem dude. It pauses the whole loop for 1, not a single object.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand what you mean by "a single object." Could you explain? I guess I just don't see what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I actully want a pause for certain set of objects, like U can say next 5:10 objects not 1:5 objects.

Comment: Ok, then you should use a conditional range inside your for-loop. `if (ii>5 && ii<10) pause(1); end`